# How can use a list or array variable in scipy.odeint

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations

I am currently working on an SEIR model and I have a list variable that represents lockdown level  *'ld'*. So for each day, the lockdown could be different. but I need a variable to work as an index for the list. I tried using 't' as an index but the value of 't' can be float and it doesn't increment one at a time.

`ld = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]`

```
def SIRD_model(y, t, alfa, beta, gamma, M):
      S,E, I, R, D = y
      dS_dt = (-beta*S*I) #+mi*E*I  
      dE_dt = (beta*S*I - alfa*E)+ ld[t]*S*I
```

This is not the complete function. In dE_dt I am using ld[t] to show the effect of lockdown.

Should I use For loop to solve these diff equation as I have seen in some Matlab codes or is there a way to use the list in odeint.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you need is called "interpolation", given a function table, extract approximate values at any given argument. You have the function `numpy.interp` and the interpolation function constructor `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` available to perform these calculations.

Of course in the most primitive case of a zero hold with integer nodes, you could also use `ld[int(t)]`. You should then also pass the maximum time in the `tcrit` optional parameter so that hopefully no indices out-of-bound are accessed.

`ld` should directly influence the `beta` value in both occurrences of the transaction term, your current application makes no sense.